# how to send two HTTP Requests at the same time

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, webrequest

I created a method, which  gets data from Foursquare(for venues), and Google(for streets), based on a latitude,longitude address I provide. It is intended to show locations around you. The name of the results from the two apis are then put together in a list

It looks something like this:

```
 var httpFoursquareResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpFoursquareWebRequest.GetResponse();
 var httpGoogleResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpGoogleWebRequest.GetResponse();
 List<string> foursquarePlacesNames=getNames(httpFoursquareResponse);
 List<string> googleStreetsNames=getStreets(httpFoursquareResponse);
 var result=foursquarePlacesNames.Union(googleStreetsNames);
 return result;
```

Problem:
1) I want the requests to be sent at the same time(so I don't have to wait for the first to get the second). But if I use AsyncCallbacks, how can I do that union, given the fact that I will have two responses handled by two different threads.

2) If more than 5 seconds pass and I have no response from one of the services, I want to return whatever data I have, and not care about the response anymore

How would you go about implementing something like this? I think it is a quite common scenario, but I didn't find any solutions on the web.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Asyncmanager for this thing.
Please get thetwo link for this. This would help you.

1.http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/calling-web-services-asynchronously

2.http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/multithreadasyncwebservice05262007094719AM/multithreadasyncwebservice.aspx